# Why is a large integer changed into the wrong value?

Tags: php

I have this code and the issue is it's giving output from `$2,147,483,647` where as I have set `3000000000` that is `$3,000,000,000`

And I want out from what we set there in form but if we choose higher `$2,147,483,647` it start from `$2,147,483,647`

Here are my codes.

```
$v = isset($_GET['v']) ? (int) $_GET['v'] : 3000000000;
```

First time it gives correct. But when we change the value in the form it gives the wrong output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're encountering a case of [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), as the maximum value of PHP's integer is 2^31-1 which evaluates to 2147483647.  PHP handles integer overflow by just limiting values to the edge of the bounds they go beyond.

To solve this, you can use a [float](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), which has a much larger range of values.  There are several ways to declare a number as a float, such as using E notation or via casting, both as shown below.

```
$v         = isset($_GET['v']) ? (float) $_GET['v'] : 3E9;
```

Answer (score 2):

2147483647 is the integers limit. Change the datatype to `bigint` or `float`.

Comment: Is there even a `longint` / `bigint` in php?

Comment: int = 2,147,483,647
bigint => 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: Yeah - Bigint as a datatype exists in mysql, but I don't think it exists in PHP. Could you point me to the manual page describing this datatype to correct my unknowing? ;)

Comment: this works **$v = isset($_GET['v']) ? (float) $_GET['v'] : 3000000000;**

Answer (score 2):

2,147,483,647 is the maximum an 32bit integer can hold. 
For bigger numbers you might have to work with the [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extensions or try getting your hands on a 64bit version of PHP. Using float might also be a possibility as it could store longer numbers (however they won't be as precise anymore).

Comment: Im very new on php so if i can fix this code with simple changing in codes that will help me thanks.